# Select all elements' data-field-id using JQuery

Tags: jquery, selector

I am trying to be super-concise, and have the following javascript code that listens for custom triggered events:

```
var concat = "";
$("body")
    .unbind("__evt_selgrps_ok")
    .bind("__evt_selgrps_ok", function(event, param) {
        $(param).each( function() {
            concat += $(this).attr("data-field-id");
        });
    });
```

The event is triggered using code as follows:

```
$("body")
    .trigger('__evt_selgrps_ok', 
    [$("#<%=DialogID%>").find(":input:checked")]);
```

Simply, the above gets all the input fields of Checkbox type, that are currently checked, and passes the array of elements as a parameter to the bound handlers (as per the first code example in this question).

Functionaly, this code works well. I just think that there is a lot of code to do something relatively simple, and that is to pass the "data-field-id" attribute values of all checked checkboxes, as a parameter to the trigger.

Ideally, a simple json array of the values passed to the trigger handler would be much better. The trigger handler shouldn't really have to know about the input element, because it just wants to receive the array of attribute values.

I suppose, the bottom-line of my question is, how do you ask JQuery to give you an array of all the specified attribute using a certain selector.

I am only interested in a very nice concise solution, which preferably doesn't involve using the 'each' function.

Thanks!
SR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to project an array of attributes from a set of elements:

```
var fieldIds = $("#<%=DialogID%> :input:checked").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("data-field-id");
}).get();
```

In your case, you could use it like this:

```
$("body").trigger("__evt_selgrps_ok",
    $("#<%=DialogID%> :input:checked").map(function() {
        return $(this).attr("data-field-id");
    }).get());
```

Comment: One note on this solution, it appears that with JQuery, you have to pass the parameter is square brackets if it is an array. Otherwise, JQuery will only pass the first element of the array.

Comment: Also, on the trigger handler, to "dereference" the object when using $(param).each(), the way to get the base object back in the each( function() { ... }) is to use $(this)[0].valueOf(). There might be a better way?

Comment: @SolidRegardless, strange, I was under the impression that you could pass an array directly, without wrapping it in another array. The documentation does not mention anything like this. Concerning your second comment, you can use `$.each(param, function() {})` instead of `$(param).each(function() {})` to work with raw values instead of jQuery objects.

Comment: Yeah it is strange. I am not sure whether it is my version of JQuery that I am using (i.e. a bug), but it is certainly happening. I am using a fairly recent version (1.8.2).